# ENCTYPE issue with asp upload

Tags: forms, asp-classic

I'm using ASP classic, I need to send a file and get the textfields to insert on a DB, I did put the ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" on the form but when I submit it gives me this error:

> "Wrong Content-Type. Make sure you have included the attribute
>   ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" in your form."

What is strange is that when a leave up the textfields and keep just the file fields it works.

Form:

```
<div data-role="content">
<form method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="formteste.asp" >

<div class="ui-field-contain">
<label for="text-4">text1:</label>
<input type="text"  data-clear-btn="true" name="text1"  value=""></div>

<div class="ui-field-contain">
<label for="text-4">text2:</label>
<input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="text2"  value=""></div>

<div class="ui-field-contain">
<label for="date-4">Date:</label>
<input type="date" data-clear-btn="true" name="date" id="date-1" value=""></div>

<input type="file" data-clear-btn="true" name="file-1" id="file-1" value="">

<input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Go">

</form>
</div>
```

and ASP:

```vb
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload.1")

text1 = Upload.Form("text1")

Upload.OverwriteFiles = False
On Error Resume Next

Upload.SetMaxSize 1048576   ' Limit files to 1MB
Upload.Save("c:/")
For Each File in Upload.Files
  arquive = File.FileName
next    

For Each Item in Upload.Form
  Response.Write Item.Name & "= " & Item.Value & "<BR>"
Next
If Err <> 0 Then 
%>
<div>"<% = Err.Description %>"</div>
<% end if%>
```

I've searched a lot for this, but none could help with my issue, I hope to get some response.

Comment: any change if you move `text1 = Upload.Form("text1")` after the `Upload.Save("c:/")` line ?

Comment: [the manual](http://www.aspupload.com/manual_simple.html) says `IMPORTANT: The Upload.Files and Upload.Form collections are populated by the Upload.Save method. Therefore, it is incorrect to reference either collection before the Save method is called: `

Comment: Got it, now it seems to work well, had some problems with a Jquery too, because asp somehow couldn't get the enctype too.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the [AspUpload Reference](http://www.aspupload.com/manual_simple.html)
>
> ***IMPORTANT**: The Upload.Files and Upload.Form collections are populated by the Upload.Save method. Therefore, it is incorrect to reference either collection before the Save method is called.*